# Get sql data if have a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table :

```
id           device         createdAt                 type
1            700           2018-09-06 10:00:00        atos
2            700           2018-09-06 09:30:00        farkos
```

The idea is to verify if in last x hours I have in this table only data `type = atos`.

For that case I want to get a `false` as result. If this table will have only `type = atos` in last h hours the result expected should be true.

I tried like this and after that check with php but not very good idea (I want to do that in sql only) whitout additional treatment :

```
SELECT * FROM table t 
WHERE t.device = 700 
AND t.createdAt >= '2018-09-05 11:00:00'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will do what you want. It looks at all the entries in the time specified and if any of them is not `atos`, will return 0 (false). Otherwise it will return 1 (true).

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN t.type != 'atos' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
FROM table1 t
WHERE t.device = 700 AND t.createdAt >= '2018-09-05 11:00:00'
```

If you want to check for the last h hours, change the `WHERE` clause to

```
WHERE t.device = 700 AND t.createdAt >= NOW() - INTERVAL h HOUR
```

Answer (score 1):

Use case when:

```
SELECT deviceid,case when min(case when type='atos' then 1 else 0 end)=0 then false when min(case when type='atos' then 1 else 0 end)=1 then true end as val FROM table 
t 
WHERE t.device = 700 
AND t.createdAt >= '2018-09-05 11:00:00'
```

group by deviceid

Comment: Not works very good. If I have 2 `type = atos` I get 2 times `val 1`

Comment: This doesn't work if there is more than one entry since '2018-09-05 11:00:00'

Comment: But in my case I can have multiple entry for this period

Comment: @George modified the ans

Comment: Still doesn't work if there's an `atos` and a `farkos`

Comment: Yes, I'm agree with @Nick

Comment: so, if you've two entry with atos and farkos with single id then what is your expected output?

Comment: So if : 
1. one atos and one farkos -----> only false
2. only atos --------------------------> only true
3. no atos -----------------------------> only false